# How can I get my wife to stop nagging about a few murders?

Tags: fable-3

I killed a few people in a town.. then I decided to try to make amends. I bought some properties and set them to low rent/price. Then I tried to make friends with a few of the townspeople. One thing led to another and before I knew it, I became married to one of these townspeople. Most of the townspeople still hate me, and my wife keeps bringing up the murders in my past, particularly during sex (which is quite the mood killer).

Is there anyway to get my wife (and the townspeople) to forgive me of my past crimes?

Comment: Have you considered killing her too?  I understand that corpses/zombies are generally pretty "meh" about your past.

Comment: My God, the question titles that pop up all ins.

Answer (score 22):

[This thread](http://www.gamespot.com/fable-iii/forum/is-there-a-way-to-stop-people-calling-me-a-murderer-57001998) suggests that what you need is to get in-game time to pass and to advance the story further, if you can. (There is a mention of 8 in-game days, but no source to support it.) It may also help to do good deeds along the way. You should be able to measure success in the same way you've noted a lack of success so far: as story time and in-game time passes, people should be referring to you as less of a jerk (and murderer) and more of a nice guy as far as murderers go. Eventually, your crime spree will be a thing of the past.

To make this less of a problem in the future, you might consider killing people in front of a smaller audience ... perhaps an audience of none? Dead NPCs, as they say, tell no tales.

Comment: Heh I did commit two murders without getting any attention in another town. Never got caught by guards. Just took a hobo in an empty building and shot them. took another hobo into the building. When she realized I killed the other hobo... well you know what I had to do

Comment: @Earlz: You didnt try the old "He was like that when i got here..." line?

Comment: "And more of a nice guy, as murderers go" You know, once you get past the whole bullet thing he's really not such a bad guy :)

Comment: I may need to look into this game...

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, the only definite solution is to kill her. Both me and players I'm friends with have fallen into this irritating trap. While I'm open to the possibility that everyone will eventually shut up about me being a murderer, I haven't found any evidence that it will ever happen. Everyone I've talked to hasn't had any luck.

If you're less of a cynic than me and want to give it a shot, try doing a bunch of good deeds. Spend time going around town and impressing people. Don't kill anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

I think over time most towns people will forgive/forget but it might take a lot of bribing for you wife. When in doubt take her on a long journey through balverine infested woods.